Required Packages for Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel in .NET for Android 9.0
There is probably a very simple straightforward answer, but I can't seem to find it. In a previous Project I had the following using statement:
using Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel;
However, I now receive the following error message:
CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Maui' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The reason (or one of) the reasons I need this is for the Platform Class. What NuGet Package(s) do I need in order to use Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel? Thanks!
